# Player is falling through the floor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I've tried everything. The player falls through regardless of what kind of GameObject (cube etc) I place under it. It has a circle collier and a rigidBody.

How can I stop the object from  falling through the floor

I should mention that, the player is supposed to die once it comes in contact with anything, so I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: A collider....Since it's a 2D Object, did you attach 2D collider to both the object and the floor?

Comment: Yes, I have attached the 2D Collider on the floor. yet it manages to fall through

Comment: Not just to the floor but to the other object too. Also, isTrigger must be disabled on both. If this is what you have done then post a screenshot of both GameObject's Inspector.

Comment: If I disable isTrigger for my player then it won't be able to go through the other objects which I need it, to go through.

Answer (score 5):

If Object is falling through the floor, here are the things to check.

**1**. Is Collider attached to that Object? If not then attach Collider or Collider2D to that Object.

**2**. Is isTrigger enabled on any of that Object Collider? If yes, then disable IsTrigger on both colliders.

**3**. If Rigidbody is attached to the GameObject then make sure that the player is 100% above the floor before clicking "Play" or you will experience even more problems.

**4**. The size of the GameObject might be small. Really small. There is a limit on what size the Object can be before it can collide with another Object. Try resizing the Object then move the camera back.

> If I disable isTrigger for my player then it won't be able to go
>   through the other objects which I need it, to go through.

This isn't a problem at-all. You can use layers to make Unity set which colliders can collider with another. Just disable the isTrigger then use:

**For 2D**:

```
Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(yourFirstCollider, yourOtherCollider, true);
```

or

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(yourLayer, yourOtherLayer, true)
```

**For 3D**:

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(yourFirstCollider, yourOtherCollider, true)
```

or

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(yourLayer, yourOtherLayer, true);
```

This will let the player not go through the floor but go through any other Objects you want. You can also do this from the Editor Settings... *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Physics* -->  or *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Physics 2D*

> the player is supposed to die once it comes in contact with anything,
>   so I don't know how to approach this

This is unrelated to the problem but `OnCollisionEnter2D` is used to detect collsion. You can call `Destroy` on the player.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Destroy(player);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you also need to detect when the player touches other colliders but don't want them to actually collider then you can do what I described above and then add child Objects with collders to player. These Child Objects will have `isTrigger` **enabled**. You can then use thee `OnTriggerEnter` function to detect when there is a collision between those objects that's not a floor.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm kind of a noob with Unity atm, probably kind of a stupid question but do I paste this code into the player script ?
`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(yourFirstCollider, yourOtherCollider, true);`

Comment: Check the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html) for a full example. You need to pass the Collider2D to the function. By the way, I recommend you use `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision` instead which you only need to pass the layer number. `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(3,5,true)` which means no collsion between layer 3 and layer 5. Google "How to create layers in Unity" for more info.